# multiple SQL tables with PHP to generate sitemap

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml, sitemap

I have a sitemap that's generated with PHP and actually its calling only the table retailers as below:

```
$query = "select * from retailers WHERE status='active' ORDER BY added DESC";
```

and construct as:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{  
    $i_url = SITE_URL.'loja/'.$row['slug_title'];
    $year = substr($row['added'],0,4);
    $month  = substr($row['added'],5,2);
    $day  = substr($row['added'],8,2);
    $i_date = ''.$year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.'';

    // you can assign whatever changefreq and priority you like
    // changefreg - optional
    // priority - optional
    echo  
    '
    <url>
    <loc>'.$i_url.'</loc>
    <lastmod>'.$i_date.'</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
    ';
}
```

The problem is, only retailers page its coming, i need to get some more 3 tables, but i can't think on a way to call and construct more things inside that, maybe a PHP condition?

Thanks to everyone for your time!

Comment: Do your other tables also use `slug_title` and `added` as column headings?

Comment: Sorry, i'm a new at this, what you mean about column heading? yes, they have the same slug_title, but they'll have a bit more field, like category and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to create a function to handle the queries or subqueries you need

Like
Main Code

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{  
    $i_url = SITE_URL.'loja/'.$row['slug_title'];
    $year = substr($row['added'],0,4);
    $month  = substr($row['added'],5,2);
    $day  = substr($row['added'],8,2);
    $i_date = ''.$year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.'';

    $data = subquery('what i need here', 'another param');

    echo  
    '
    <url>
    <loc>'.$i_url.'</loc>
    <lastmod>'.$i_date.'</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
    ';
}

function subquery($firstparam, $secondparam)
{
  $myquery = "SELECT * FROM ".$firstparam;
  //more code

  $result = 'my query result';

  return $result;
}
```

With this you can call a subquery based on the main query, you can create more funcionts or create only one with different types that, can able you to do different queries in one function.

Comment: Well, if i understand, on $myquery i can handle multiple SELECTs?

Answer (score 0):

Since the tables all have the same fields we need (`slug_name` and `added`), we can just loop through each table with the same procedure, then output to sitemap.xml file.

```
    // Our Echo Buffer
    $buffer = array();

    // Table Names
    $tables = array( 'retailers', 'table2', 'table3', 'table4' );

    // Using MySQLi, cause it's Improved.
    $conn = new MySqli( 'localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database' );

    // Iterate over $tables
    foreach( $tables as $table )
    {
        // Build Query
        $query = "SELECT `slug_name`, `added` FROM $table" .
                 " WHERE status='active' ORDER BY added DESC";

        // Get Result
        $result = $conn->mysqli_query( $query );

        // Iterate over Result
        while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() )
        {
            // Chop up the Date
            $date = substr($row['added'],0,4) . '-' .
                    substr($row['added'],5,2) . '-' .
                    substr($row['added'],8,2);

            // Add page details to $buffer
            $buffer[] = '<url>' .
                        '<loc>' . SITE_URL . 'loja/' . $row['slug_title'] . '</loc>' .
                        '<lastmod>' . $date . '</lastmod>' .
                        '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>' .
                        '<priority>0.8</priority>' .
                        '</url>';
        }
        // Free MySQLi Result
        $result->close();
    }

    // Output the Buffer to view. Make sure it looks good.
    echo implode( "\r\n", $buffer );

    // Remove the echo above and uncomment below if it looks good.

    // if( ( $xml = fopen( 'sitemap.xml', "w" ) ) !== FALSE )
    // {
    //     fwrite( $xml, implode( "\r\n", $buffer ) );
    // }
```