# generating sitemaps using php

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

While generating sitemap using php and mysql i am totally stuck with the errors in this, my requirement was to gerante multiple files sitemaps with the sitemap index if urls are greater than 5000 but this code i followed which is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19304151/3606257 totally stuck me with errors please help me in this regards will be thankful to you my code is here

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'mysite');
define('DB_USER','mysite');
define('DB_PASSWORD','mysite');
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$site_baseurl = "http://localhost/mysite/";
 // Table Names
include("config.php");
$buffer = array();
    $tables = array( 'tblusers', 'tblshares', 'tblreviews');
    $custom_pre = array( 'users/', 'shares/', 'reviews/');
    $pirorities = array( '0.8', '0.9', '1.0');


    // Iterate over $tables
    foreach($tables as $table and $custom_pre as $custom_pres and $pirorities as $piroritie)
    {
        // Build Query
        $query = "SELECT `seo_url`, `added` FROM $table" .
                 "ORDER BY added DESC";

        // Get Result
        $result = mysql_query( $query );

        // Iterate over Result
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
        {
            // Chop up the Date
            $date = substr($row['added'],0,4) . '-' .
                    substr($row['added'],5,2) . '-' .
                    substr($row['added'],8,2);

            // Add page details to $buffer
            $buffer[] = '<url>' .
                        '<loc>' . $site_baseurl . $custom_pres . $row['seo_url'] . '</loc>' .
                        '<lastmod>' . $date . '</lastmod>' .
                        '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>' .
                        '<priority>' . $piroritie . '</priority>' .
                        '</url>';
        }
        // Free MySQLi Result
        $result->close();
    }

    // Output the Buffer to view. Make sure it looks good.
    echo implode( "\r\n", $buffer );

    // Remove the echo above and uncomment below if it looks good.

    // if( ( $xml = fopen( 'sitemap.xml', "w" ) ) !== FALSE )
    // {
    //     fwrite( $xml, implode( "\r\n", $buffer ) );
    // }


?>
```

Comment: **stuck me with errors** - What errors? Apart from the logical one in the `foreach` statement

Comment: These three errors Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_AND, expecting ')'

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in 

Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on a non-object in

Comment: @user3606257 Please edit your question and include the error in your post, instead of posting them on comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `foreach` statement is wrong. You cannot pass 3 groups in. Only one.

The following should sort you out.

```
foreach($tables as $index => $table) {
    $custom_pres = $custom_pre[$index];
    $piroritie = $pirorities[$index];
    //.. continue.
}
```

You're using `mysql`, but not in an object-oriented way, so you cannot call `close()`. Use [the procedural style.](http://php.net/mysql_close)

```
mysql_close($con);
```

#### Obligatory note.

Please don't continue using `mysql_*` functions as they have been deprecated and dropped. Please consider using [**`PDO`**](http://php.net/pdo) or [**`MySQLi`**](http://php.net/mysqli)

[image]